# Models registered in workspace do not show up in Designer (preview)

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I registered a model in my AML workspace, and I can see it in the Model List:

[Model List view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtL5Q.png)

But I cannot see it in Designer (preview), which prevents me from using the new model there.

[Designer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpvIb.png)

Looks like a bug to me. Datasets work fine.

Comment: Actually it's by design, since Designer (with only built-in modules) doesn't allow user to write their own code to consume the model, then list the model there make no sense.

Comment: Showing the registered model in Designer is in road-map together with the custom module.

Comment: you can also send an email to AzCommunity@microsoft.com to discuss in detail and add you to the private preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known issue as the models registered in workspace cannot be consumed in Designer without the new custom module capability (in private preview) available.

The models showing up in Designer today are these generated from Designer training -> inference pipeline conversion and can only be used in Designer (not registered in the workspace).
We have an effort ongoing to reduce the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback.
This is Blanca, working on AML Designer.
We're working on aligning models concept to reduce the confusion.
Shall we set up a meeting for us to understand your scenario to use registered model in Designer?
Your inputs will greatly help us to better design the user experience.
Could you please contact keli19@microsoft.com?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!